# cannot find this simple regex

Tags: regex

i'm trying with `#(?:[a-fA-F0-9]{2}[,])*(?:[a-fA-F0-9]{2}(?!,)){0,1}#`
to match the following lines:

```
#1C,B4,97,A3,EF,CF,5A,4A#   //should  match
##  //should  match
#1C#  //should  match
#01# //should match
#1C,1C,1C,1C,# //should not match
#1C,# //should not match
#1C # //should not match
# 1C# //should not match
#11C# //should not match
#11C,,1C# //should not match
#1# //should not match
#ZZ# //should not match
```

but on regex101 it only matches the first line, why?
thank you

Comment: Just tried it on regex101: matches lines 1, 3, 4. Which is correct; line 2 should not match.

Comment: Why should `#01#` match but `#11C#` should not?

Comment: I want hex frames byte per byte

Comment: @Ruud Helderman weird, maybe I put a space in the command...5 and 6 work but should not. I updated (once in the post) the first regex because that was not the one I was using...sorry about that

Comment: That's because you made the second half of your regex optional by `{0,1}`; that leaves `[,]` as a potential ending.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this regex:

```
#(?:[a-fA-F0-9]{2}(?:,[a-fA-F0-9]{2})*)?#
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/VjUHMc/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `#`: Match `#`
- `(?:`: Start non-capture group

  - `[a-fA-F0-9]{2}`: Match 2 hex characters
  - `(?:`: Start 2nd non-capture group

    - `,`: Match a comma
    - [a-fA-F0-9]{2}`: Match 2 hex characters
  - `)*`: End 2nd non-capture group. `*` makes this group repeat 0 or more times
- `)?`: End non-capture group.`?` makes this match **optional**
- `#`: Match `#`

Comment: Or for regex dialects that understand a word boundary: `#(?:[a-fA-F0-9]{2},?\b)*#`